# reCAPTCHA and PHP to send an Email Form

Tags: php, html, email

I'm using GoDaddy as my web server.

I'm trying to implement reCAPTCHA into my email form for my website, however it seems to not be able to work.  That is, I pass the reCAPTCHA test but the email isn't sent.

I've only used PHP and HTML for the site so far.

I have also added the script to my head tag

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

Here are the code snippets.

HTML:

```
<form action="#" id="form" method="post" name="form">
      <div class="form-group">
             <label for="name-field">Name</label>
             <input name="vname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" type="text" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
             <label for="email-field">Email address</label>
             <input name="vemail" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Your Email" type="text" value="">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
             <label for="contract-field">Enter Contract Here</label>
             <textarea name="msg" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Contract Here" rows="5"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="g-recaptcha form-group" data-sitekey="SITEKEY"></div>
      <div class="form-group"><button id="send" name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button></div>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
//Checking For reCAPTCHA
$captcha;
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])){
    $captcha=$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
// Checking For correct reCAPTCHA
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($response.success==false){
    echo "Your CAPTCHA response was wrong."
    exit;
}
else{
    // Checking For Blank Fields..
    if($_POST["vname"]==""||$_POST["vemail"]==""||$_POST["msg"]==""){
        echo "Fill All Fields..";
    }
    else{
        // Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
        $email=$_POST['vemail'];
        // Sanitize E-mail Address
        $email =filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        // Validate E-mail Address
        $email= filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if (!$email){
            echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
        }
        else{
            $to = 'johdoe@example.com';
            $subject = 'Test';
            $message = $_POST['msg'];
            $headers = 'From:'. $email . "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
            // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
            // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
            mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
            echo "Your mail has been sent successfully!";
        }
    }
} else {
    echo "Your CAPTCHA response was wrong.  Try again."
    exit;
}?>
```

Am I implementing server-side wrong?  Or is it client side?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has syntax errors in if and else. Just rewrite your code as given below and try it.

```
<?php
//Checking For reCAPTCHA
$captcha;
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
}
// Checking For correct reCAPTCHA
$response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEY&response=" . $captcha . "&remoteip=" . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if (!$captcha || $response.success == false) {
    echo "Your CAPTCHA response was wrong.";
    exit ;
} else {
    // Checking For Blank Fields..
    if ($_POST["vname"] == "" || $_POST["vemail"] == "" || $_POST["msg"] == "") {
        echo "Fill All Fields..";
    } else {
        // Check if the "Sender's Email" input field is filled out
        $email = $_POST['vemail'];
        // Sanitize E-mail Address
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
        // Validate E-mail Address
        $email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        if (!$email) {
            echo "Invalid Sender's Email";
        } else {
            $to = 'johdoe@example.com';
            $subject = 'Test';
            $message = $_POST['msg'];
            $headers = 'From:' . $email . "\r\n";
            // Sender's Email
            // Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
            $message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n");
            // Send Mail By PHP Mail Function
            if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
                echo "Your mail has been sent successfully!";
            } else {
                echo "Failed to send email, try again.";
                exit ;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I was able to send and receive the email however the problem now is that I can just ignore the reCAPTCHA.  Any idea why?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit the code and write it again, just have a look in 5 minutes

Comment: I solved it!

I made this `if ($response . success == false) {` into this `if (!$captcha || $response.success == false) {`. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Cool, actually $response.success has got nothing to do. It returns true every time.