# reCaptcha v2 and PHP in email form

Tags: php, html, recaptcha

So I have found this solution in this forum:

[reCAPTCHA and PHP to send an Email Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28273491/recaptcha-and-php-to-send-an-email-form/28273633)

I have added the script in my header and added my keys in the email form and in my PHP code as specified in the above solution (the link above). I have added the PHP code on the same contact.php page where I have the form, but at the top of the page before the HTML. However, whenever I load the contact.php page, I get this answer right away - before the form loads:

"Your CAPTCHA response was wrong."

What am I doing wrong?

Do you agree that I should replace "SECRETKEY" below with my unique secret key I have received - everything else should stay the same in that part of the code?

```
$response=file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=SECRETKEY&response=".$captcha."&remoteip=".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

if($response.success==false){
echo "Your CAPTCHA response was wrong."
exit;

Comment: I know this is not an answer or comment you're looking for, and I mean this is the most helpful, constructive way possible... but please consider not using reCaptcha. It's extremely user UNfriendly. The internet has become a worse place due to reCaptcha. There are tons of very effective, ready to use, easy to implement Captcha solutions that don't fend off legit users nearly as much as reCaptcha does.

Comment: @RocketNuts - please let me know of other solutions that are easier so implement and more user friendly. It's not that I have a preference for Captcha, I just want to ensure I don't get spammed through my form. What can you recommend that is easy to implement (only using HTML and PHP) and can help prevent spam from bots and the like?